# How to return next year values when you're in the current year, but keep current values when you switch to next year? which becomes current year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that runs a user selects a certain month. It returns various values based on a month selection. Using MS SQL Server

Problem: 
It returns those values based on the month and it works as it should up until a user chooses January. When January is chosen, it brings back both this current year (which has already passed) and this upcoming January (January 2020. Which is what they want). How do I remove the 2019 values when next year is chosen, but also keep them when the year changes to the next year?

Here is the query

```
SELECT distinct 
       RRP.Id, RRP.UniqClient, RRP.Client, RRP.Expiring_Policies, RRP.UniqBroker, 
       CONVERT(varchar, RRP.ExpDate, 101) AS ExpDate, RRP.NewUw, RRP.OtherContact, 
       RRP.Company, RRP.Broker_Name, RRP.Reviewed, RRP.DateCreated, RRP.DateUpdated, 
       RRP.EmailCreated, RRP.UniqProducer, RRP.LINES, 
  CASE WHEN MMS.UniqMarketingSubmission IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [MMS Created]
  FROM  dbo.Reviewed_Renewal_Policy AS RRP LEFT OUTER JOIN
  GREEN43_PROD_REPL.dbo.MarketingSubmission AS MMS ON RRP.UniqClient = MMS.UniqEntity AND RRP.ExpDate = MMS.EffectiveDate 

  where (RRP.Reviewed = 'No') AND (DATENAME(month, RRP.ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month, 3, GETDATE()))) 

  order by ExpDate ASC
```

Typically there is a .NET webforms variable in place of the 3 in DATEADD, but the 3 works in SQL and I kept it for clarity

I have tried messing with comparing current dates and adding a year, but nothing successful so far. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functions there...)

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read. (And to write...)

Comment: @jarlh I edited it to show I'm using MS SQL server

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou . . . I'm a little confused on where the user is choosing anything in this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition in where cause, try it.

```
AND YEAR(RRP.ExpDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I did try that before, but it only brings back this current year of course.  I tried using AND YEAR(RRP.ExpDate) <> YEAR(GETDATE()) .. which brings back the correct results, but it won't work once the year changes

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value for three months in the future, I would suggest:

```
where RRP.Reviewed = 'No' and
      RRP.ExpDate >= datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, 3, getdate()),
                                   month(dateadd(month, 3, getdate()),
                                   1) and
      RRP.ExpDate < datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, 4, getdate()),
                                   month(dateadd(month, 4, getdate()),
                                   1)
```

Note:  This is constructed so it can use an index on `(Reviewed, ExpDate)` or `(ExpDate)`.

Comment: I left off the superfluous selection code. Since I can accomplish the exact same thing in MSSM running the query normally, it seemed silly adding a bunch of html. Where you placed that 3 and 4 is a asp:Parameter variable called "@ExpDate" .. it suffices on the html side and runs this query the exact same way. I don't need three months in future. The 3 is there because it happens to be October and 3 months ahead is January. I would put a 2 there if it was November. My issue is only retrieving 2020 results when it's 2019, but keeping them when it's 2020

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou . . . If you want January of next year, then use `datefromparts(1 + year(getdate()), 1, 1)` and `datefromparts(1 + year(getdate()), 2, 1)`. for the bounds.

Comment: I was able to come up a with a solution(which I posted below), but yours is also a great additional solution. I appreciate the help. I'll edit mine below and add yours to show how it fits as well.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the help I was given. I managed to answer my own question. I found an example of this solution from another question. I modified it to fit my own.

```
SELECT distinct  
           RRP.Id, RRP.UniqClient, RRP.Client, RRP.Expiring_Policies, RRP.UniqBroker, CONVERT(varchar, RRP.ExpDate, 101) AS ExpDate, 
            RRP.NewUw, RRP.OtherContact, RRP.Company, RRP.Broker_Name, RRP.Reviewed, RRP.DateCreated, 
            RRP.DateUpdated, RRP.EmailCreated, RRP.UniqProducer, RRP.LINES, CASE WHEN MMS.UniqMarketingSubmission IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [MMS Created]

            FROM  dbo.Reviewed_Renewal_Policy AS RRP LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GREEN43_PROD_REPL.dbo.MarketingSubmission AS MMS ON RRP.UniqClient = MMS.UniqEntity AND RRP.ExpDate = MMS.EffectiveDate 

     where ((RRP.Reviewed = 'No') AND (DATENAME(month, RRP.ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month, 4, GETDATE()))) 
            AND Month(getdate()) <= Month(RRP.ExpDate)) 
            OR
            ((RRP.Reviewed = 'No') AND (DATENAME(month, RRP.ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month, 4, GETDATE()))) 
            AND Month(getdate()) > Month(RRP.ExpDate) AND Year(RRP.ExpDate) > Year(getdate())) 
            order by ExpDate ASC
```

This brings back the current year values and when the next year values when the appropriate selection is made.

OR an Alternative thanks to Gordon Linoff above

```
SELECT distinct  
            RRP.Id, RRP.UniqClient, RRP.Client, RRP.Expiring_Policies, RRP.UniqBroker, CONVERT(varchar, RRP.ExpDate, 101) AS ExpDate, 
            RRP.NewUw, RRP.OtherContact, RRP.Company, RRP.Broker_Name, RRP.Reviewed, RRP.DateCreated, 
            RRP.DateUpdated, RRP.EmailCreated, RRP.UniqProducer, RRP.LINES, CASE WHEN MMS.UniqMarketingSubmission IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [MMS Created]

            FROM  dbo.Reviewed_Renewal_Policy AS RRP LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GREEN43_PROD_REPL.dbo.MarketingSubmission AS MMS ON RRP.UniqClient = MMS.UniqEntity AND RRP.ExpDate = MMS.EffectiveDate 
    where ((RRP.Reviewed = 'No') AND (DATENAME(month, RRP.ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month, 3, GETDATE()))) 
            AND Month(getdate()) <= Month(RRP.ExpDate)) 
            OR
            ((RRP.Reviewed = 'No') AND (DATENAME(month, RRP.ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month, 3, GETDATE()))) AND
            datefromparts(1 + year(getdate()), 1, 1) <= RRP.ExpDate and datefromparts(1 + year(getdate()), 2, 1) >= RRP.ExpDate) 
            order by ExpDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example of how much easier it is to read formatted sql. I took the OPs posted answer and formatted it a bit. Removed several extra sets of parenthesis and moved around a little logic so it was a bit simpler.

```
SELECT distinct RRP.Id
    , RRP.UniqClient
    , RRP.Client
    , RRP.Expiring_Policies
    , RRP.UniqBroker
    , CONVERT(varchar, RRP.ExpDate, 101) AS ExpDate
    , RRP.NewUw
    , RRP.OtherContact
    , RRP.Company
    , RRP.Broker_Name
    , RRP.Reviewed
    , RRP.DateCreated
    , RRP.DateUpdated
    , RRP.EmailCreated
    , RRP.UniqProducer
    , RRP.LINES
    , CASE WHEN MMS.UniqMarketingSubmission IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [MMS Created]
FROM  dbo.Reviewed_Renewal_Policy AS RRP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GREEN43_PROD_REPL.dbo.MarketingSubmission AS MMS ON RRP.UniqClient = MMS.UniqEntity 
                                                                AND RRP.ExpDate = MMS.EffectiveDate 
where RRP.Reviewed = 'No'
AND DATENAME(month, RRP.ExpDate) = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(Month, 4, GETDATE()))
AND
(
    Month(getdate()) <= Month(RRP.ExpDate)
) 
OR
(
    Month(getdate()) > Month(RRP.ExpDate) 
    AND 
    Year(RRP.ExpDate) > Year(getdate())
) 
order by ExpDate ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. I was trying to be helpful and provide as much clarity as possible on the question. I see how yours gives a lot more clarity to a reader. I'll use your advice on the next one.

Comment: You should follow nice and tidy formatting not just for questions, but for every query you write. It will save you and the people who follow you a lot of time and effort. :)